# Rails 3: using non-Active Record objects with form_for

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3, form-for

Is there any documentation, or advice?

Answer (score 21):

You can use Active Model

Take a look [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model).

Look at the source code at [Github](https://github.com/railscasts/219-active-model).

Comment: The ActiveAttr[1] or Virtus[2] gems are also useful in addition to ActiveModel.

[1] http://railscasts.com/episodes/326-activeattr
[2] https://github.com/solnic/virtus

Comment: This answer is 3 years old. Do you know any updates to this method?

Answer (score 0):

Using ActiveAttr is the more modern way of doing this.

Gem: https://github.com/cgriego/active_attr
Railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/326-activeattr