# Keep fields filled after raised exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following controller trying to catch an exception:

```
  def create

    status = 'ok'
    begin
      # do something dodgy
      @factura = Factura.execute_procedure :store_prueba, 1
      flash[:notice] = "Éxito"
    rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid
      flash[:notice] = nil
      flash[:alert] = "Algo salio mal"
      status = 'bad'
    end
      if status == 'ok'
        render action: 'new'
      elsif status == 'bad'
        redirect_to action: :back
      end
  end
```

Flash messages apparently work, but input fields doesn't keep filled if the exception is raised. 
Keep in mind **i'm not using models, i'm using store procedures** to perform this operation, so that's the reason I don't have a   `@factura = Factura.new(factura_params)` or something.

Here it is the view:

```
<% if flash[:alert] %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible"><%= flash[:alert] %></div>
<% end %>
<% if flash[:notice] %>
    <div class="alert alert-sucess alert-dismissible"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>

<%= form_tag({controller: "facturas", action: "create"}, method: :post )  do |f| %>

  <!--<div class="form-inputs col-lg-6 panel panel-default col-lg-9"  >-->
    <div class="panel-body">
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <%= label_tag "Folio:" %>
        <%= text_field_tag :folio, nil, class: "form-control", required: "true" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4">
        <%= label_tag "Fecha:" %>
        <%= date_field_tag :fecha, Date.current.to_default_s , class: "form-control", required: "true" %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <%= label_tag "Almacen:" %>
        <%= select_tag "almacen", "<option></option>".html_safe, class: "form-control col-lg-6", required: "true",
        data: { placeholder: "Seleccione Almacen", toggle: "popover", placement: "top", content: "Debe seleccionar Almacen"} %>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <%= label_tag "Cliente:" %>
        <%= select_tag "cliente", "<option></option>".html_safe, class: "form-control col-lg-6", required: "true",
        data: { placeholder: "Seleccione un cliente", toggle: "popover", placement: "top", content: "Debe seleccionar Cliente" } %>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="panel-content no-more-tables">
    <table id="detalle" class="col-md-12 table table-bordered table-striped table-condensed no-more-tables cf">
      <thead class="cf">
        <tr>
          <th>Artículo</th>
          <th>Cantidad</th>
          <th>Precio</th>
          <th>Importe</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td data-title="Artículo">
              <div class="input-group col-md-4">
                <select onchange="obtener_ultimoprecio(this)" name="detalle_arreglo[][articulo]" data-placeholder="Seleccione un artículo" class="articulo form-control col-md-4" required="true"></select>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td data-title="Cantidad">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon"></span>
                  <input class="form-control" type="number" aria-label="Cantidad" name="detalle_arreglo[][cantidad]" step="0.001" min="0.000" onchange="cambiar_importe(this)" required="true">
              </div>
            </td>
            <td data-title="Precio" >
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="number" class="form-control" aria-label="Precio" name="detalle_arreglo[][precio]" onchange="cambiar_importe(this)" step="0.001" min="0.000" required="true">
              </div>
            </td>
            <td data-title="Importe">
              <div class="input-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
                  <input type="text" class="importe form-control" aria-label="Importe" name="importe" step="0.001" min="0.000" readonly="true" onchange="calcular_importe_total(this)">
              </div>
            </td>
            <td data-title=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="borrar_renglon(this)">Cancelar</button></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label aria-label="Total Importe">Total Importe:</label>
    <div class="input-group col-lg-4 pull-right">
      <span class="input-group-addon">$</span>
        <input class="form-control" id="importe_total" type="text" aria-label="Total Importe" readonly="true" >
    </div>
  </div>
<span class="row"></span>
  <div class="panel-content">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" onclick="nuevo_renglon()" aria-label="Agregar otro producto">+</button>
  </div>
<br>
    <div class="form-actions panel-footer">
      <%= submit_tag("Generar", :class => "btn btn-danger") %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Note that I'm using select2 v4, so I don't expect to get filled again on those

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without the view code but in your unsuccessful path, you need to set `@factura` to have same values that came in `params...`. This way Rails will render a `new` view with that data (assuming you are using `form_for @factura` in your view).

Comment: I'm not using a form_for tag, I'm using form_tag because form_for is when you are using activerecord with models (as it should be).

Comment: Then it won't work. Right now your form has no object passed from the controller. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241779/rails-3-using-non-active-record-objects-with-form-for